# How can I filter models data based on the foreign key in Django views?

Tags: python, django, filter, models

I have two models, User and UserRating, connected by a one to many relationship how can I filter the ratings of a particular user so I can calculate his overall rating and show it on his profile. Thank you.

```
#this is model for user
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    email = models.EmailField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    #password = forms.CharField(max_length=32, widget=forms.PasswordInput)
    profilepic = models.ImageField(null=True)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    secondname = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    city = models.ForeignKey(City)


#this is the model for user ratings - one to many relationship with User
class UserRating(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
    comment = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    rating = models.IntegerField(default=5)
```

Answer (score 2):

If you have a `User` object you can access all his ratings by [reverse relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/es/1.9/topics/db/queries/#related-objects):

```
user.userrating_set.all()
```

To calculate his average rating use [`Aggregation`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/topics/db/aggregation/)

```
from django.db.models import Avg
user.userrating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))
```

### Edit

If you want this as a property of the user model do this:

```
class User(models.Model):
    username = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)
    ... 

    @property
    def avg_rating(self):
        return self.userrating_set.all().aggregate(Avg('rating'))
```

Then you can access it with

```
user.avg_rating
```

Comment: You could create this as a property on the User model.

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT** - updated so you can divide by number of ratings

In a view...

```
from django.db.models import Sum

current_user_rating_object = UserRating.objects.filter(user=request.user)
ratings = current_user_rating_objects.count()
total_rating = current_user_rating_object.aggregate(Sum(total_rating=Sum('rating', distinct=True))['total_rating']
weighted_rating = total_rating / ratings
```

Comment: Thank you. However, how can I divide that value on the total number ratings to get the average.

Comment: Edited above... this could be more compact but hopefully you can see how each part works.

Comment: Use `Avg` instead of sum (see my answer)